# How to use HTML5 SSE with PHP and python

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, server-sent-events

I want to check simple if my API endpoints are alive but I got back `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at myURL` error, I'm on 94.0.1 (64-bit) windows edition, which is based on [this](https://caniuse.com/eventsource) is supported. And I'm trying this on AWS-ec2. All of this is based on this article: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

This is my `HTML`:

```html
 <div id="searchDatabases"> 
 </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
                // Yes! Server-sent events support!
                var source = new EventSource("pingServers.php");
                source.onmessage = function(event) {
                    document.getElementById("searchDatabases").innerHTML = event.data + "<br>";
                };

              } else {
                // Sorry! No server-sent events support..
                console.info("Not supported browser!");
              } 
            </script>
```

this is in `pingServers.php`

```php
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');


    $output = shell_exec("python3 pingServers.py")

    echo $output;

    flush();
```

and this is `pingServers.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import json 
import html
import sys

requestpost = requests.post('MyJSONEndpoint.php')
if requestpost.status_code == 200:
    print('OK')
else:
    print('not OK')
```

So my question is how can I do this correctly?

Comment: What part of the puzzle is broken? Does the browser make the request? Does that request not complete? What does `requests.post('MyJSONEndpoint.php')` do? Have you tried with the most basic SSE endpoint with no `shell_exec`?

Comment: the python part works fine from terminal the php part didn't show up anything even on `echo "something"; flush();`

Comment: I had no luck invoking a Python script using `shell_exec`,`exec` or `passthru` but `system('python helloworld.py');` worked fine

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius separately, without SSE on php7 it  worked to me the `shell_exec` too.

Comment: I can't even do a working version of the linked original w3schools example on xampp, is it a working one?